# Cloud masking for sentinel surface reflectance multi-images.But I cant apply for multi-images using Google Earth Engine JavaScript API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I want to do cloud masking for sentinel surface reflectance images but I cannot apply for multi-images,It was done for first image.

How could I do that using the Google Earth Engine JavaScript API?

```
var cld = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:cloud_masks')

var s2SR = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
              //filter start and end date
             .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2013,2021,'year'))
             .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1,12,'month'))
             //filter according to drawn boundary
             .filterBounds(geometry)
             .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESSMENT', 'less_than',50);
//var first = ee.Image.constant(0) // init image

//var first = ee.Image(s2SR.get(0))
var test_image = s2SR.first()

Map.addLayer(test_image, {bands:['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min:0, max:8000}, 'test image')

// adding mNDWI function
var addMNDWI = function(image) {
  var mndwi = ee.Image(image).normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B11']).rename('MNDWI');
  return ee.Image(image).addBands(mndwi);
};
 var mndwı=ee.ImageCollection(test_image)
             .map(addMNDWI);
 Map.addLayer(mndwı, {bands:['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min:0, max:400}, 'mndwı')


var masked = cld.sclMask(['cloud_low', 'cloud_medium', 'cloud_high', 'shadow'])(test_image)
Map.addLayer(masked, {bands:['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min:0, max:3000}, 'masked')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by mapping entire collection with function (**s2SRMasked**) of following [script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/91fd271cf6d97b5377022d391a9aa6bc). There it was used an arbitrary point geometry because you didn't include one.

```
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Point([-109.647021484375, 39.40057454539126]);

var cld = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:cloud_masks');

var s2SR = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
              //filter start and end date
             .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(2013,2021,'year'))
             .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(1,12,'month'))
             //filter according to drawn boundary
             .filterBounds(geometry)
             .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESSMENT', 'less_than',50);
//var first = ee.Image.constant(0) // init image

print("s2SR", s2SR);

//var first = ee.Image(s2SR.get(0))
var test_image = s2SR.first();

Map.addLayer(test_image, {bands:['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min:0, max:8000}, 'test image');

// adding mNDWI function
var addMNDWI = function(image) {
  var mndwi = ee.Image(image).normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B11']).rename('MNDWI');
  return ee.Image(image).addBands(mndwi);
};
 var mndwı=ee.ImageCollection(test_image)
             .map(addMNDWI);
 Map.addLayer(mndwı, {bands:['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min:0, max:400}, 'mndwı');


var masked = cld.sclMask(['cloud_low', 'cloud_medium', 'cloud_high', 'shadow'])(test_image);

print("masked", masked);
Map.addLayer(masked, {bands:['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min:0, max:3000}, 'masked');

var s2SR_list = s2SR.toList(s2SR.size());

var s2SRMasked = s2SR_list.map(function (img) {
  
  return cld.sclMask(['cloud_low', 'cloud_medium', 'cloud_high', 'shadow'])(img);
  
});

print('s2SRMasked', s2SRMasked);
```

Comment: Couldn't I use this in certain polygon area,should it necessarily be a point?

Comment: No, you can use your polygon area. In my case, I used a point because it was easier to put one and testing my approach (you didn't include your polygon geometry).

Comment: I mean,I want to use this code for all images on the black sea border,but I cant. I want to see all of images